# How to show and hide ad banners in game over class?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iad

To import the banners, I have the following

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "platform/ios/CCEAGLView-ios.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface RootViewController()

@end


@implementation RootViewController
```

To show the ad banners i have the following in my RootViewController.mm:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

The problem is in my game, the ad shows throughout the entire game, and I just want the banner to appear once the gameover.cpp initializes. How would I do this? The GameOver class is in C++ and the RootViewController is in Obj C.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for show and hide ad banner:

```
- (void)showiAdBanner
 {
    if( !_adView ) { // only add to view if it's not already there
        _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50)]; //initialize it
        _adView.delegate = self; // set delegate
    }
    _adView.hidden = NO; //reveal it
    _bannerIsVisible = YES; //set bool to yes
}

- (void)hideiAdBanner {
   _adView.hidden = YES; //hide it
   _bannerIsVisible = NO; // set bool to no
}
```

call this two method wherever you want to show and hide.